# order directives in bootstrap 4 not working in mobile emulator or mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The **order column** directive in the following code works when I resize the browser window to mobile width. However, when I run it in **mobile emulator or actual mobile device**, the order columns are not working. This is due to @media queries not working on mobile. Other solutions on the forum is recommending use of 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`

However, that meta tag is not helping here.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row align-items-center py-8 py-md-11">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 mt-2">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div>
        <h3>
          Feature 1
        </h3>
        <p>
          sometext
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div>
        <h3>
          Feature 2
        </h3>
        <p>
          sometext
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 order-sm-first order-md-first order-lg-last">
    <div class="mb-8 mb-md-0">
      <div id="native-awesome-landing-page-tools" class="img-fluid img-animation lottie shadow-dark">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Eglinton_Valley_NZ_01.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-center py-8 py-md-11">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7">
    <div class="mb-8 mb-md-0">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 mt-2">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div>
        <h3>
          Feature 1
        </h3>
        <p>
          sometext
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div>
        <h3>
          Feature 2
        </h3>
        <p>
          sometext
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Feature 1

sometext

#### Feature 2

sometext

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
If this line is not present then none of your media query would work.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be entered just after the `<head>` tag.